# "Вы неверно ввели адрес электронной почты" для подписки на stackoverflow.com

Tags: поддержка

Хочу подписаться на вопрос или ответ, а мне пишет "Вы неверно ввели адрес электронной почты". А где эти настройки чтобы указать\изменить адрес электронной почты для  stackoverflow.com не могу разобраться.

Comment: данный вопрос стоит задать на StackOverflow META.

Comment: Добавьте больше подробностей, скриншоты соответствующие с ошибками. Не очень понятно пока.

Comment: Я не смог найти где и как изменить мыло\пароль в профиле потом нашел эту ссылку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery первый раз я заходил через яндекс без регистрации, а сейчас изменил на почту mail-ru и пароль. Надеюсь что ошибок с подписками не будет.